# How to open/download static files via anchor links within an MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownLoad_Files()
{
    return View();
}
```

**View** [DownLoad_Files.cshtml ]:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="docs/TestFile1.doc">File 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="docs/TestFile2.pdf">File 2</a></li>
    ....
</ul>
```

**Error** [When clicking on one of the above links]:

```
This localhost page can’t be found

No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:50507/ControllerName/docs/TestFile1.doc
Search Google for localhost 50507/ ....TestFile1.doc
HTTP ERROR 404
```

**Question**: How can I make the above links work so that the linked file gets open (i.e downloaded) in a browser? **Note**: I'm trying to follow this official ASP.NET Core tutorial on [Serving Static Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files) and have created `docs` folder under `wwroot` folder

Comment: try `href="~/docs/TestFile1.doc"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `~/` as the prefix of the path

```
<a href="~/docs/TestFile1.doc">File 1</a>
```

This should work assuming your docs folder is inside `wwwroot` directory of your app

`~/` indicates a path starting from the app's content root. In asp.net core, it will be the `wwroot` by default.

Now when user clicks on the link, based on the browser & browser settings, it will either ask the user a prompt where they can choose to download the file to a directory or open it in a browser (if the browser has a supporting plugin to show the document type)

Comment: Thanks for explanation as it may help others like me.